# Bookshelf.js withRelated query for id in array of target model

Tags: sql, bookshelf.js, knex.js

Looking for a way to use bookshelf.js withRelated to find related items where the primary key exists in an array of foreign keys.

```
bookshelf.model( 'User', {
  tableName: 'users',
  organizations: function() {
      return this.hasMany(Organizations, 'team');
  },
});

bookshelf.model( 'Organization', {
  tableName: 'organizations',
  defaults: {
     team: [1, 2, 3]
 }
});

User.where({id: 1}).fetch({withRelated :['organizations']})
  .then(function(user) {
    //error
    // Unhandled rejection error: select "organizations".* from 
       "organizations" where "organizations"."team" in ($1) - malformed array literal 
});
```

Comment: Your foreign key should not be in an array when you define the has many relationship. You may be confusing the optional notation in the documentation for an array

Comment: @vbranden thanks. the optional notation allows you to specify the column name in your Target model. So in this case rather than looking in a user_id column in the Target Organization Model (which would be bookshelfs default) its specifying to look in the Team column.

Comment: I know how it works. What I'm saying is that it should be a string not an array as you have it in your example code

Comment: Thanks. I still get the 

`Unhandled rejection error: select "f9jNA6Yy_organizations".* from "f9jNA6Yy_organizations" where "f9jNA6Yy_organizations"."team" in ($1) - malformed array literal: "VknUKZ04l""`

Comment: If you take out the defaults do you still get the error? I don't think you can set a default value for a column as an array

Comment: Yes, the defaults are just to show how the column is represented in the database for that model.

Comment: The column is set as a type text[]

If i change this.hasMany(Organizations, 'team'); to reference a column that is a string it does not through an error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97165/discussion-between-user3243725-and-vbranden).